# How to target Syntax highlighter with CSS to change font size of code on display

Tags: css, wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking to target the wordpress syntax highliter with css to change the default font size, I cannot add any usefull css classes to the div's and I cannot seem to target it without targeting all div's globally!

Here's the complete css path from g-chrome, from the auto generated div right the way through to the code.

```
 div#"individual-ID-for-each-code-example-here".syntaxhighliter div.lines div.line.alt1 table tbody tr td.content code.string
```

I've tried targeting .syntaxhighliter and all the others, including pre with no luck, is there something simple I'm missing here?

Here's the html:

```
<pre class="brush: php; title: ; notranslate" title="">

<!--CODE GOES HERE-->

</pre>
```

If it helps, here is the page-itself:

http://msc-media.co.uk/blog/

Comment: Umm, a gh. Using `div#highlighter_ ID goes here .syntaxhighlighter div.lines div.line.alt1 table tbody tr td.content code.string` works. With `!important` as an override of course. Is the bounty still open or is this solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem in using this way:

```
.syntaxhighliter table tbody tr .code code.string {
    font-size: 12pt !important;
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image: SyntaxHighlighter]

#### Full image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqIyt.png)...

Comment: I've updated the CSS path as it's changed slightly, could you take another look?

Comment: Updated the answer too, does it work? Is there a place where we can check out the working HTML?

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify your `shThemeDefault.css`?

Comment: I just added this `.syntaxhighlighter code {font-size: 20px !important;}` in your `shThemeDefault.css` and it was working. Check out using Google Chrome's Sources panel itself. Will post a screenshot if needed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17673/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-mchandler)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Praveen Kumar for your contribution, but the .css file directed to would only have changed the font size on the default theme, If I ever chose to swap themes in the future, the font size would revert back.

I changed the font-size in the shCore.css as this will apply to all of the theme templates. (Line 56 in syntax highlighter 2).

The CSS mentioned:

```
.syntaxhighlighter,
.syntaxhighlighter div,
.syntaxhighlighter code,
.syntaxhighlighter table,
.syntaxhighlighter table td,
.syntaxhighlighter table tr,
.syntaxhighlighter table tbody
{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    background: none !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    float: none !important;
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    position: static !important;
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    line-height: 1.1em !important;
    font-family: "Consolas", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-style: normal !important;

    font-size: 0.98em !important; <- This! (Reduced from 1em, surprisingly this was enough)

    /*min-height: inherit !important; *//* For IE8, FF & WebKit */
    /*min-height: auto !important;*/ /* For IE7 */
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

Comment: But it's not fully correct, It's not fully future-proof. If I changed templates I would have to apply the change to another style-sheet, this is much simpler as it covers all the templates.

Comment: I actually didn't mention the CSS File at all. I just asked you if you can add the css. I just took the reference from there. Anyways.

Answer (score 0):

With `v3.6.2`, I did it in two steps.

1. In the `SyntaxHighlighter Settings`, set `Additional CSS Class(es)` to something like "myCustomClass`.
2. In `Appearance` > `Additional CSS`, enter the following:

```
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass a,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass div,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass code,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass table,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass table td,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass table tr,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass table tbody,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass table thead,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass table caption,
.syntaxhighlighter.myCustomClass textarea {
  /* custom styling goes here */
}
```